# What does the "=> any" signify?

Tags: typescript

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021484/how-can-i-add-optional-callbacks-to-a-typescript-function) s/he refers to:

```
getJSON(url: string, success?: (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => any): JQueryXHR;
```

I understand the "success?: (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR)" part - that's saying there is an optional function called on success that has those 3 typed parameters.

But what does the "=> any" signify in this? Does it mean the function can return any type of object? That doesn't make sense as the success function logically is of type void.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct; `void` is the correct way to type this function's return value.

In practice, there isn't really a difference between `any` and `void` return types in callback positions because the compiler does not enforce that functions with a type of `any` have a `return` statement.

Comment: Am I correct that the "=> any" signifies it is returning any type. I understand you saying the correct return is void, but what is the difference between "=> any" and " : any"?

Comment: `=>` is used in the "function type shorthand" type syntax: `(n) => x` is sugar for `{ (n): x; }`.

Comment: Oh... ok that makes sense. So you do this as it adds the {}. Thank you.